# Is it possible to use adjustbox and qtree in the same document?

Tags: graphics, packages, adjustbox, qtree

Using the packages adjustbox and qtree simultaneously causes the error:

> Package graphics Error: Division by 0.
>   \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{myimage.bmp}

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{adjustbox} %Lets table extend beyond margins
\usepackage{qtree} %Allows drawing of syntax etc trees '\Tree'

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[hp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{myimage.bmp}
        \caption{My image}
        \label{fig:figure1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to use them both in the same document?

Edit: This is being compiled with XeLateX.

Edit2: This bug only occurs with .bmp, and not with .png files; changing file format is a fine workaround.

Comment: Using the code with \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image} everything is fine. You can test it... . I think its a problem with `myimage.bmp`.

Comment: I'd be half-surprised to learn that this works without those two packages and solely `graphicx` loaded instead. Two thoughts: (1) use a different file format; (2) if sticking with bitmaps, you probably need to use the `bmpsize` package.

Comment: do you really mean that if you remove qtree from that document that it works?

Comment: Yes, if I remove qtree it works absolutely fine. Without adjustbox, this MWE gives an "undefined control sequence" error for \includegraphics.

I have a (much much larger) document with a dozen packages, and got this error when I added adjustbox for the first time. I deleted packages one by one to try to create a MWE, and found that qtree was the only one that combined with adjustbox to give the Division by 0 error.

Comment: @jon: Why would changing file format fix the adjustbox/qtree clash problem? I'm not doubting you, I just don't understand how TeX works very well. Could you point me at some explanatory documentation?

Comment: Well, as `adjustbox` loads `graphicx` (which is where the `\includegraphics` command comes from), the  question becomes: does `qtree` conflict with `graphicx`?  But I mean don't use bitmaps as a matter of general practice. I can't actually reproduce the problem, however, so I'm not suggesting it as *the* solution, just a possible workaround. (Tonight, I'll  try again with another `.bmp` file.)

Comment: If you change `myimage.bmp` to `example-image-a`, does the example work? I have no idea where I'd get a BMP from. But there is certainly no essential conflict if `adjustbox` and `qtree` work with other image formats.

Comment: The rest of the images in my document are .png files, and there are no issues with those. I will convert the problematic one and leave the question of .bmp files unanswered.  (As to why .bmp - it was generated by another program, and I didn't think it mattered enough to convert it to .png. Now I know!)

Comment: I'm surprised BMP works at all, no matter what you load. It seems to be specific to certain backend drivers, including XeTeX.  I agree the problem you describe sounds very odd, though.

Answer (score 1):

BMP images are not really supported. Maybe XeLaTeX has some support, but PDFLaTex definitifly hasn't. The "division by 0" error comes from `graphics` package (loaded by `graphicx` which in turn is loaded by `adjustbox`) and is caused most likely has the original width can not be extracted from the BMP file and is therefore 0. When using the `width` key I guess the original width is used in a division and then the error is caused.

So I would heavily recommend to convert you BMP Image to a PNG Image using an external image tool. Most modern tools can do this and the conversion is lossless.